# Displaying active conda virtual environment in terminal via .bash_profile

Tags: bash, terminal, anaconda, conda

**Problem**

I am trying to customize my Terminal to show key information more clearly, and colour code it.

I am currently having an issue when activating a new conda virtual environment, where it duplicated the name twice.

I have tried implementing $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV, $CONDA_PREFIX in the .bashrc file to no avail and have also played around editing the .bash_profile anaconda code through trial and error.

**.bash_profile**

```
# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
# . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"  # commented out by conda initialize
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

# !! Connects to .bashrc file for customization !!
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

**.bashrc**

```
green=$(tput setaf 71);
white=$(tput setaf 250);
reset=$(tput sgr0);

PS1="\[${green}\](\$(basename \$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV)) ";  # virtual env
PS1+="\[${white}\] $(pwd)/\W";                          # current directory
PS1+="\[${white}\] \n ";                                # new line
PS1+="\[${reset}\]-> ";                                 # code prompt
export PS1;
```

**Output**

As you can see below (flask_env) once activated repeats itself and only the second entry is formatted green:

```
(base)  /Users/AlexBargh/~
 -> conda activate flask_env
(flask_env) (flask_env)  /Users/AlexBargh/~
 ->
```

**Desired Output**

If i run `source .bashrc` again in the terminal this issue seems to resolves itself - just want to code it in.

I am trying to get rid of the first (flask_env) entry just to keep (base) and (flask_env) both formatted green.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Side note: don't forget to cover the case where `$CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV` is undefined. Right now you're going to error out whenever you deactivate out of **base**.

Answer (score 0):

You have `CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false` only in one of three code paths through your setup logic. Could it be that the first branch with `\eval` is taken instead, so that conda changes PS1 after all?

Try setting `export CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false` unconditionally.

Comment: Yeah, it almost certainly follows the first branch - this is default for launching an interactive shell. The other branches are for when someone calls `bash -l foo.sh` so that the script will be executed in the default Conda env, but Conda won't bother with changing `PS1`. What you suggest isn't quite best practice, since Conda provides a configuration option for that (i.e., `conda config --set changeps1 False`). However, OP really doesn't want to disable the `PS1` change, but supplement it, so I'm not sure it's appropriate here.

Comment: On second thought, disabling Conda's PS1 change is probably the easiest solution, since it always prepends to the existing PS1, and the OP already has something that works independently of Conda's manipulations. I'd be happy to upvote were you to change the recommendation to `conda config --set changeps1 False`.